# Paged Datasource With Pages Enumerated in .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, pagination, devexpress, datasource

I've used paged datasource but I need page numbers to be listed on the .aspx like this

**1 2 3 4 5 ... 16   next   last**

How to achieve this? any idea?

Or please suggest me another way of paging. I can devexpress tools too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You can use `LinkButton`, with `Server.Transfer` or `ResponseRedirect` methods.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="1"/>
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="2"/>
.....

  void LinkButton1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     Server.Transfer("...");
  }
```

Note :

1. You can add dynamically your linkbuttons with PlaceHolderControl
2. You can use TreeView Control Navigation
3. You can use Menu Control Navigation
4. You can use WizardStep Control
5. You can also try with [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11418/Pager-Control-for-ASP-NET) custom library

Comment: And dynamically add LinkButtons ? As I don't know how many pages are there in db

Comment: You can add dynamically your linkButton with PlaceHolder control

Comment: But for me it's very easy with menu control, because this control is made for navigation

Comment: try with this library also : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11418/Pager-Control-for-ASP-NET

Comment: I meant a good exampl about menu control. pagination. many thanks \